# Removing Duplicating Issue in MySQL views

Tags: mysql, view

I have two tables called `transactions` (TransactionID, HotelID, service..) and `services` (id, userid, HotelID, type) and I need to create view from there. In here 1st table has 15 tuples and 2nd one has 8 tuples.

When I wrote this SQL query:

```
CREATE VIEW summary
AS
    SELECT TransactionID, userid, HotelID, service
    FROM transactions, services
    WHERE transactions.HotelID = services.name
```

I got 105 results in summary view. How I get rid of this duplication issue.

Comment: Could you please create a sql fiddle with the data

Comment: Shouldn't your condition be transactions.HotelID=services.HotelID instead

Comment: can you show us table structure for better understanding ?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as i understands your question, i think you need to use group concate and group by using join query.
using group by and group concate duplication of record will be solve.
and using join you can get common data from both table.
try below query.
currently i am not having knowledge of your table structure that's why i take assumption of your query and created my own tables and as per them created query.

Eg:

> select
>   c.country_id,c.country_name,group_concat(s.state_id),group_concat(s.state_name) from country c  inner join state s on c.country_id =s.country_id group
>   by c.country_id;

if you have any query feel free to ask.